# 3-D Surface Chart Bands in Excel 2010 - VBA to ctrl transparency

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to write VBA code to make a band in a 3-D Surface Chart transparent and/or semi-transparent. When I recorded a macro, manually clicking on the legend, then the band, and then changing its properties Excel 2010 recorded the following code:

```
ActiveChart.Legend.Select
ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries(47).Select
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Transparency = 1
    .Solid
End With
```

But when I try to execute, I get an error message saying that the "Format.Fill" isn't supported.

The code I used to change the colors of the bands is:

```
 With Worksheets("Sheet23").ChartObjects(1).Chart.Legend.LegendEntries(BandCount)
    .LegendKey.Interior.Color = RGB(Red(BandCount), Green(BandCount), Blue(BandCount))
    .LegendKey.Shadow = 1 
 End With
```

Does anyone know how to modify this code to control transparency as well?
Thanks!

Comment: See **[this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6f632515-2557-4c77-848f-7540225c6aa6/problem-with-excel-2010-vba-and-charts)** on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
```

use this:

```
With Selection.LegendKey.Format.Fill
     .Visible = msoTrue
     .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
     .Transparency = 0.5          <-- Or whatever value of transparency you want
     .Solid
End With
```

This is based upon the approach recommended by G North in **[this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6f632515-2557-4c77-848f-7540225c6aa6/problem-with-excel-2010-vba-and-charts)**.